# what is apostrophe type in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

I have condition that uses the member function:

```
(cond ((member '1' (some-function)) (display #t)) (else (display #f)))
```

it works fine but i still couldn't find the answers to:

1)what is the type of '1'?

2)i have the next expression

> (lambda(x)(= x 1))

how can I convert to the same type of '1'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that the `cond` expression is not doing what you think. What's really happening is this:

```
(cond ((member '1 '(some-function))
       (display #t))
      (else
       (display #f)))
```

In other words: the number `1` is being quoted and the expression `'(some-function)` is being interpreted as a single-element list with the symbol `some-function` as its only member. Regarding the first question, this expression:

```
'1'
```

… is invalid in Scheme - try typing it in the evaluation window, nothing will happen: the first quote applies to the number `1`, and the second quote is expecting further input, so anything that's written after it will get quoted. FYI double quotes mean a string, as in many other languages: `"1"`. But a *single* quote indicates a *quoted* expression, that evaluates to itself:

```
'1
=> 1
```

And it's just shorthand for this:

```
(quote 1)
=> 1
```

Which in the above expression is unnecessary, a number already evaluates to itself:

```
1
=> 1
```

Now, about the second question, it doesn't make sense because `'1'` is not a type, as explained above.

Comment: thanks! for the 2nd question, how it's possible to use (lambda(x)(= x 1)) in the cond(insted of a single-element list)?

Comment: @user3453625 it's not clear what you want to do. Use the function for what? `member` receives two (or three) parameters: a value, a list (and optionally a function). So let's say that `1` is the value and `(lambda(x)(= x 1))` is the function … where is the list? what do you want to return?

Answer (score 4):

`'x` is the same as `(quote x)`. Scheme won't evaluate the argument so it's basically how you do constant values. It's not a single quote around rather you have two elements in the list quoted in your example like this:

```
(cond ((member '1 '(some-function)) (display #t)) (else (display #f)))
```

You never need to quote a number since it's always evaluated to itself. `'1` is the same as just `1`